# Load List-like string into List in Python

Tags: list, python-2.7

I want to load a `.txt` file having data directly into a Python list. I am expecting some functions that would be as fast as `cPickle`.
The `.txt` file contains data like this:

```
[[[10127,24857],1],
[[10127,24866,24874],1],
[[10127,24866,493908],1],
[[10127,24866],1],
[[10127,24867,80672,493103,604379],1],
[[10127,24871],1]]
```

Comment: Please update your question with the reason/ground of your expectation. In my experience you are unlikely to find anything as fast a `cPickle` for plain text like that. `cPickle` data formats (there are multiple)  are close to the internal structure of the Python data structures and has advantages for loading, like indication of data length up-front, which has enormous speed advantages over parsing character by character to find end-of-line.

Comment: @Anthon This is easy to corroborate using the `timeit` module: `python -m timeit -s 'import cPickle; s = cPickle.dumps([[10127,24867,80672,493103,604379],1], -1)' 'cPickle.loads(s)'` measures 2 usecs on my machine, while equivalent timing of `eval` and `ast.literal_eval` (e.g. `python -m timeit -s 'import ast; s = "[[10127,24867,80672,493103,604379],1]"' 'eval(s)'`) take 22 and 34 usecs respectively. In other words, the `literal_eval` approach recommended by nKandel is not exactly slow, but `cPickle` **is** an order of magnitude faster, and really hard to beat speed-wise.

Comment: I will have (500mb - 1 GB) of file dumped everyday. I need to be able to process them, At the first hand read the file fast and effectively. eval sucks! I am using json.loads currently which is workable solution. However, I might write my own streamReader if results are not as good as expected using json.loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import ast
>>> x = u'[ "A","B","C" , " D"]'
>>> x = ast.literal_eval(x)
>>> x
['A', 'B', 'C', ' D']
>>> x = [n.strip() for n in x]
>>> x
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

[ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

Comment: This is a good answer regarding functionality, but the OP did ask for an approach "as fast as pickle". While `ast.literal_eval` is not slow, it is an magnitude slower than `cPickle.load`.

Comment: literal_eval() doesnt have anyway to hint the function saying what literal syntax ( list, dict, tuple etc) the function should expect. It will evaluate for all possible literal syntax, Hence it doesn't perform.